# python - ls-l problems executing popen

Tags: python, linux

I have a remote shell that does not work very well. When I run the command ls -l brings me a good result, but when I run the following command, ls -l runs again. i dont know which one my is error. 
I use linux and python 2.7

server.py

```
import socket, shlex
import subprocess

PORT = 9999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('',PORT))
sock.listen(4)

sc, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    comando = sc.recv(255)
    if comando == 'exit':
        break   
    else:
        print comando
        if " " in comando:
            comando = shlex.split(comando)
            shell = subprocess.Popen(comando,bufsize=255, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)

        else:
            shell = subprocess.Popen(comando, shell=True, bufsize=255,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
        stdout, stderr = shell.communicate()
        if not stdout:
            stdout = shell.stderr.read()
        if len(stdout) == 0:
            stdout = "[Comando ejecutado]"

    sc.send(stdout)

sc.close()
sock.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket, sys, os
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 9999))

mensaje = ""
while mensaje != "exit":
    mensaje = raw_input("Shell# ")
    try:
        s.send(mensaje)
        resultado = s.recv(2048)
        print resultado 
    except:
        print "Hubo un error en la conexion..."
        mensaje = "exit"          

print "bye..."

s.close()
```

I guess the error is with popen and childs

Comment: You should probably remove `shell=True`

Comment: thanks for comment, but still not working

Comment: what error are you actually getting?

Comment: I meant what is the original error

Comment: after running ls-l i run another command and ls-l prints again. I have to run the command twice to work.

Comment: I don't follow, do you meant you get the output of `ls - l` twice even when running a different command and then you must run that new command again to see it's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

- don't use `shell=True` unless you have to
- `subprocess.check_output()` is the easiest way to run a command, check if it fails or not, and get the output
- when an error happens, print out the status code to help track down what's going on. Sometimes the command isn't being parsed correctly, ie a space in the filename.

## source

```
import socket, shlex
import subprocess

PORT = 9999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('',PORT))
sock.listen(5)

sc, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    comando = sc.recv(255).rstrip()
    print 'got:',comando
    if not comando:
        break
    elif comando == 'exit':
        break   

    comando = shlex.split(comando)
    print comando
    output = 'ERROR'
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(
            comando,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
            shell=False,
            )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        output = "[Comando ejecutado] status={}".format(err.returncode)
    sc.send(output)

sc.close()
sock.close()
```

Comment: after running ls-l i run another command and ls-l prints again. I have to run the command twice to work

Comment: the code exits after a command is run.  If I send the "id" command (with: "echo id | nc localhost 9998"), it correctly shows me my user ID and other info.  The server exits. I re-run it, then send the "ls" command with "echo ls -l | nc localhost 9998" -- I get the "ls" output correctly, and the server exits again.  How are you testing the server? Is the client appending a newline, or CR+LF, or neither?

Comment: sorry for not adding the client. Now add the code in the question

Comment: Client/server work for me: responses to "id" and "ls -l" are good.  I tweaked the server code, adding "rstrip()" so that it strips any trailing newline or whatever.  It works!
(I'm on Linux btw)

Comment: i never use 'rstrip()', how to use?

Comment: thanks solved. Was the recv_size and thanks for rstrip()